# Как правильно настроить работу поиска в SearchView в связке с RecyclerView, Room и LiveData?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-room, livedata, searchview

Как правильно настроить работу поиска и обновление RecyclerView?
В программирование новичок.
Не хватает знаний и умения правильно настроить работу SearchView.
Из базы данных загружаю и отображаю список имен.
Чтобы не листать до нужного имени весь список.
Хочу реализовать поиск через SearchView.
Он у меня не корректно работает.
Когда начинаешь вводить символы список отображает подходящие имена.
Но когда закрываешь виджет поиска.
То на экране не отображается весть список.
А остается то что было найдено.
А если ничего не было найдено, то экран пустой.

[image: Пример не правильной работы]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SearchView searchView;
NameShortAdapter nameShortAdapter;

LiveData<List<NameShort>> nameLiveData;
RecyclerView rvName;

NameListViewModel nameListViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameListViewModel = new NameListViewModel(getApplication());
    nameLiveData = nameListViewModel.getAll();


    rvName = findViewById(R.id.rvNameList);
    rvName.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    nameLiveData.observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<NameShort>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<NameShort> nameShorts) {

            nameShortAdapter = new NameShortAdapter(nameShorts);
            rvName.setAdapter(nameShortAdapter);

        }


    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            nameShortAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }


    });


    return true;
}
```

**NameListViewModel**

```
public class NameListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private AppDatabase appDatabase;

public NameListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    this.appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application.getApplicationContext());
}

public LiveData<List<NameShort>> getAll() {
    return appDatabase.nameShortDao().getAll();
}
```

}

**NameShortAdapter**

```
class NameShortAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NameShortAdapter.ItemViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private List<NameShort> nameShortList;

public NameShortAdapter(List<NameShort> nameShortList) {
    this.nameShortList = nameShortList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public NameShortAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_name_short, parent, false);

    final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(v);

    itemViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NameFullActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name_id", nameShortList.get((itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition())).name_id);
            intent.putExtra("nameLiveData", nameShortList.get((itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition())).name);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NameShortAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvShortName.setText(nameShortList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return nameShortList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            List<NameShort> nameShortListFiltered = new ArrayList<>() ;
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                nameShortListFiltered.addAll(nameShortList);
            } else {
                List<NameShort> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (NameShort nameShortRow : nameShortList) {
                    if (nameShortRow.name.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(nameShortRow);
                    }
                }
                nameShortListFiltered = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = nameShortListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            nameShortList = (ArrayList<NameShort>) filterResults.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvShortName;

    public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvShortName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShortName);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Наверное нужно при закрытии обнулять значение в searchView и получать полный список. В этом примере мне кажется не хватает копии массива данных. Т.е. после фильтрации в массиве остаются только те данные которые подходят фильтру.. посмотри другие примеры filterable адаптера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать отдельный list для фильтруемых айтемов, потому что вы здесь меняете первоначальный список айтемов

```
nameShortList = (ArrayList<NameShort>) filterResults.values;
```

Посмотрите [здесь](https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308) пример адаптера

Comment: Благодарю, помог ваш совет. Работает поиск как нужно. Все оказалось так просто. А то я полез в дебри  Transformations.switchMap и MutableLiveData.